# Failed to start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, expo

**Question i am getting error  at the start when i do npm start **

```
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this i was missing the powershell path variables  thats why i was facing the error the soloution was

```
First add Poweshell to PATH as %SystemRoot%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0.
open powershell as admin and write this command Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force.
last thing fire npm-windows-upgrade.
```

Comment: pm-windows-upgrade : The term 'npm-windows-upgrade' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and